# Running jboss outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

How do I run JBOSS 5.x outside Eclipse? I'm using Eclipse Juno latest version. One of the requirements of Automated testing is to run JBoss outside. Anybody has ideas how I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Download JBoss, install and run it. I don't get the question.
http://www.jboss.org/jbossas

Or do you mean one of the many sub-projects?

Comment: I meant to say running JBOSS from command line using Startup.bat- as opposed to from within Eclipse. There must be a special setup for running JBOSS in command line to work!

Answer (score 0):

- When you unzip jboss, you will find a sub folder called bin, inside that you should fine run.bat :-).
- From Eclipse use an ant script to create a war and copy it to the jboss deploy directory.